# how to validate each field separately?

Tags: validation, backbone.js

please help solve the problem. i make form with validation. after click on submit-button output phrase 'Great Success!' in alert-window

but i need after click on submit-button get result for particular fields(username and email) in console. my try:

```
events: {
    'click #signUpButton': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.signUp();
    }
},

signUp: function () {
    var data = this.$el.serializeObject();

    this.model.set(data);

    var modelValid = this.model.isValid(true);
    console.log('model valid', modelValid);

    var modelValidUsername = this.model.username.isValid(true);
    console.log('model username valid', modelValidUsername);        

    var modelValidEmail = this.model.email.isValid(true);
    console.log('model email valid', modelValidEmail);           

    if(this.model.isValid(true)){
        // this.model.save();
        alert('Great Success!');
    }
},
```

all code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/udXL5/595/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/#isvalid), `isValid` also accepts an attribute name (or array of attribute names) in order to validate individual fields:

```
var modelValidUsername = this.model.isValid('username');
console.log('model username valid', modelValidUsername);        

var modelValidEmail = this.model.isValid('email');
console.log('model email valid', modelValidEmail);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpxbLbor/